# Python - execute for loop in multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am new to python. for loop iterates element one by one. I want to know how to execute all the elements in the for loop at the same time.
Here is my sample code:

```
import time
def mt():
    for i in range(5):
        print (i)
        time.sleep(1)
mt()
```

It prints the element one by one from for loop and wait 1 sec for next element. I want to know how to use multi-threading in for loop to print all the elements at the same time without waiting for next element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module as shown in the example below:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def main():
    p = Pool(processes=5)
    result = p.map(some_func, range(5))

def some_func(i):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try import threading Concept.

```
import threading
import time

def mt(i):
    print (i)
    time.sleep(1)

def main():
    for i in range(5):
        threadProcess = threading.Thread(name='simplethread', target=mt, args=[i])
        threadProcess.daemon = True
        threadProcess.start()
main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It also worked for my project